# How to validate canonicals on a website

Tags: google-search-console, url, canonical-url, url-parameters, rel-canonical

I've validated canonicals on my website but, the pro webmaster have recommended me that the canonicals that I've implemented is wrong. Can you guys tell me how to validate canonicals on my website.

Thanks,

Comment: Did the "pro webmaster" not offer any clues as to what was "wrong"? How have you "validated canonicals" on your website? How have you "implemented" these _canonicals_?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the HTML of your web page. View the source code, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and type `rel=canonical`. If this tag points to the URL you want it to then it should be working.

Alternatively you can run the Canonical tag through Screaming Frog. If the Canonical tag has been implemented correctly it should return the Canonical link element.